# how to configure pagination codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, pagination

Ive trying to make a pagination with CodeIgniter, it should be so simple according the manual of Codeigniter, even in the example is like this

« First < 1 2 3 4 5 > Last »

```
$config['total_rows'] = $this->searchdesc_model->queryallrows();
$config['per_page'] = '10';
$config['uri_segment'] =4;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<p>';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</p>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<b>';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b>';
$config['first_link'] = 'First';
$config['last_link'] = 'Last';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<p>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</p>'

$this->load->library('Company_Creation');
```

in the view I only call it like this pagination->create_links(); ?> (or I send it through the view when I call it from the controller, still I only get this

1 2 3 >

and there is no way to make it look like the exmaple, may sound so dummy but , anyone could help me with this? or have a problem similar?

Thanks

EDIT 1

```
$config['total_rows'] = $this->searchdesc_model->queryallrows();
$config['per_page'] = '5';
$config['uri_segment'] =4;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<p>';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</p>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<b>';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b>';
$config['first_link'] = ' First';
$config['last_link'] = ' Last';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<p>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</p>';
$config['next_link'] = '';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<p id="nextbutton" style="padding-left:5px;">';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</p>';
$config['prev_link'] = '';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<p id="prevbutton" style="padding-right:5px;">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</p>';
$config['num_links']=4;
$data['retorno'] = $this->searchdesc_model->queryalldb($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4,0));
$config['total_rows']=1000;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

I did this according some advices Ive recieve, like you said when are many data it works good, still I'd LOVE to show first and next button all time, I set total_rows after my query (which I call with the right number of rows) , and I tried before too and the results are the same, I also need to show only 4 numbers  and I am ustying numb_links ... still doesnt work (I dont know why Ci docs say should work..) any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, that's just an example of what pagination looks like. Not the actual pagination that can be created using CodeIgniter Pagination class. You'll probably need to extend the pagination class and tweak the `create_links()` method yourself.

Comment: Thanks, any idea of how to create them by my own? (i hate that codeigniter gives those examples and they dont even give clues of how to make it...)

Comment: Which CodeIgniter version are you using?

Comment: When did codeigniter 2.3 came out? Or 2.2 as a matter of fact? All i see is, latest is 2.1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To produce what the example shows is actually pretty easy.  You just need to extend the Pagination's Library to accommodate this.  I was able to do this.  No matter how many pages you show it still shows first, last, back arrow, and forward arrow.

If you are wanting to show 5 pages at all times with the foward and back stuff you need to have that many results to fill that page.  Then you set `num_links` to what you would want before and after if on the 3rd page.  So it would be 2.  My changes if you are on the 1st page make it display 4 pages after when applicable.  See image below.  White is current page.  Green is pages available.

[image]
[image]

Hopefully I've explained everything correctly and this works for you.  Let me know.

**Controller**

```
  $this->pagingConfig = array();
  $this->pagingConfig['base_url'] = 'URL';
  $this->pagingConfig['total_rows'] = 0;//TOTAL ROWS
  $this->pagingConfig['cur_page'] = 0;//CURRENT PAGE NUMBER
  $this->pagingConfig['per_page'] = 0;//YOUR RESULTS PER PAGE
  $this->pagingConfig['num_links'] = 2;//NUMBER OF LINKS BEFORE AND AFTER CURRENT PAGE IF ON PAGE ONE WILL SHOW 4 PAGES AFTERWARDS IF YOU HAVE ENOUGH RESULTS TO FILL THAT MANY
  $this->pagingConfig['first_link'] = "&lt;&lt; First";
  $this->pagingConfig['last_link'] = "Last &gt;&gt;";
  $this->pagingConfig['full_tag_open'] = "<div class='pagination'>";
  $this->pagingConfig['full_tag_close'] = "</div>";
  $this->pagingConfig['last_tag_open'] = "";
  $this->pagingConfig['first_tag_close'] = "";
  $this->pagingConfig['anchor_class'] = "page";
  $this->pagination->initialize($this->pagingConfig);
  $strPaging = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

**EXTENDED PAGINATION LIBRARY CALL**

```
function create_links()
{
  // EDIT: ADDED THIS BECAUSE COULDN'T SEEM TO SET THIS ANYWHERE ELSE
  if ($this->anchor_class != '')
  {
     $this->anchor_class = 'class="'.$this->anchor_class.'" ';
  }

  // If our item count or per-page total is zero there is no need to continue.
  if ($this->total_rows == 0 OR $this->per_page == 0)
  {
     return '';
  }

  // Calculate the total number of pages
  $num_pages = ceil($this->total_rows / $this->per_page);

  // Is there only one page? Hm... nothing more to do here then.
  if ($num_pages == 1)
  {
     return '';
  }

  // Determine the current page number.
  $CI =& get_instance();

  if ($CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE OR $this->page_query_string === TRUE)
  {
     if ($CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment) != 0)
     {
        $this->cur_page = $CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment);

        // Prep the current page - no funny business!
        $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
     }
  }
  else
  {
     if ($CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment) != 0)
     {
        $this->cur_page = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);

        // Prep the current page - no funny business!
        $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
     }
  }

  $this->num_links = (int)$this->num_links;

  if ($this->num_links < 1)
  {
     show_error('Your number of links must be a positive number.');
  }

  if ( ! is_numeric($this->cur_page))
  {
     $this->cur_page = 1;
  }

  // Is the page number beyond the result range?
  // If so we show the last page
  if ($this->cur_page > $this->total_rows)
  {
     $this->cur_page = ($num_pages - 1);
  }

  // EDIT: DON'T NEED THIS THE WAY I'VE CHANGED IT
  // $uri_page_number = $this->cur_page;
  // $this->cur_page = floor(($this->cur_page/$this->per_page) + 1);

  // EDIT: START OF MODIFIED START AND END TO WORK HOW I WANT
  $totalLinks = ($this->num_links*2)+1;
  if($totalLinks > ($this->total_rows/$this->per_page))
  {
     $totalLinks = ceil($this->total_rows/$this->per_page);
  }
  //first page
  if($this->cur_page == 1)
  {
     $start = 1;
     $end = $start + $totalLinks - 1;
  }
  //middle pages
  elseif($this->cur_page + $this->num_links <= $num_pages && $this->cur_page - $this->num_links > 0)
  {
     $start = $this->cur_page - $this->num_links;
     $end = $this->cur_page + $this->num_links;
  }
  //last couple of pages
  elseif(($this->cur_page + $totalLinks) > $num_pages)
  {
     $start = $num_pages - $totalLinks + 1;
     $end = $num_pages;
     //check to see if this is in the first half of links so it doesn't jump the paging
     if($this->cur_page <= $this->num_links)
     {
        $start = 1;
        $end = $start + $totalLinks - 1;
     }
  }
  //first couple of pages
  elseif(($this->cur_page - $totalLinks) < 1)
  {
     $start = 1;
     $end = $start + $totalLinks - 1;
  }
  // EDIT: END OF MODIFIED START AND END TO WORK HOW I WANT

  // EDIT: CODEIGNITERS BASE PAGING SETUP SEE ABOVE FOR MY CHANGES
  // $start = (($this->cur_page - $this->num_links) > 0) ? $this->cur_page - ($this->num_links - 1) : 1;
  // $end   = (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages) ? $this->cur_page + $this->num_links : $num_pages;

  // Is pagination being used over GET or POST?  If get, add a per_page query
  // string. If post, add a trailing slash to the base URL if needed
  if ($CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE OR $this->page_query_string === TRUE)
  {
     $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url).'&amp;'.$this->query_string_segment.'=';
  }
  else
  {
     $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url, '/') .'/';
  }

  // And here we go...
  $output = '';

  // Render the "First" link
  // EDIT: CHANGED TO ALWAYS SHOW FIRST LINK AT LEAST
  if  ($this->first_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page != 1)
  {
     $first_url = ($this->first_url == '') ? $this->base_url."1" : $this->first_url;
     $output .= $this->first_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$first_url.'">'.$this->first_link.'</a>'.$this->first_tag_close;
  }
  else
  {
     $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$this->first_link.$this->cur_tag_close;
  }

  // Render the "previous" link
  // EDIT: CHANGED TO ALWAYS SHOW PREVIOUS LINK AT LEAST
  if  ($this->prev_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page != 1)
  {
     $i = $this->cur_page-1;

     if ($i == 0 && $this->first_url != '')
     {
        $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a  '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->first_url.'">'.$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
     }
     else
     {
        $i = ($i == 0) ? '' : $this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix;
        $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a  '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$i.'">'.$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
     }

  }
  else
  {
     $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$this->prev_link.$this->cur_tag_close;
  }

  // EDIT: CHANGED THIS TO ALWAYS SHOW ALL LINKS WANTED EVEN IF ON FIRST PAGE
  // Render the pages
  if ($this->display_pages !== FALSE)
  {
     // Write the digit links
     for ($loop = $start; $loop <= $end; $loop++)
     {
        // EDIT: DON'T NEED THIS THE WAY I'VE CHANGED IT
        // $i = ($loop * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;

        if ($loop >= 0)
        {
           if ($this->cur_page == $loop)
           {
              $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$loop.$this->cur_tag_close; // Current page
           }
           else
           {
              $n = ($loop == 0) ? '0' : $loop;

              if ($n == '' && $this->first_url != '')
              {
                 $output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a  '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->first_url.'">'.$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
              }
              else
              {
                 $n = ($n == '') ? '' : $this->prefix.$n.$this->suffix;

                 $output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a  '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$n.'">'.$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }

  // Render the "next" link
  // EDIT: CHANGED TO ALWAYS SHOW NEXT LINK AT LEAST
  if ($this->next_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page < $num_pages)
  {
     $output .= $this->next_tag_open.'<a  '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$this->prefix.($this->cur_page+1).$this->suffix.'">'.$this->next_link.'</a>'.$this->next_tag_close;
  }
  else
  {
     $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$this->next_link.$this->cur_tag_close;
  }

  // Render the "Last" link
  // EDIT: CHANGED TO ALWAYS SHOW LAST LINK AT LEAST
  if ($this->last_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page != $num_pages)
  {
     $i = (($num_pages));
     $output .= $this->last_tag_open.'<a  '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix.'">'.$this->last_link.'</a>'.$this->last_tag_close;
  }
  else
  {
     $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$this->last_link.$this->cur_tag_close;
  }

  // Kill double slashes.  Note: Sometimes we can end up with a double slash
  // in the penultimate link so we'll kill all double slashes.
  $output = preg_replace("#([^:])//+#", "\\1/", $output);

  // Add the wrapper HTML if exists
  $output = $this->full_tag_open.$output.$this->full_tag_close;

  return $output;
}
```

Comment: I have wrote tutorial about Cdeigniter Pagination. Please have a look and give your suggestions https://www.cloudways.com/blog/pagination-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 5):

The only reason you get `1 2 3 >` instead of `« First < 1 2 3 4 5 > Last »` is that you simply don't have enough rows in your result to generate more than 3 pages.

- The "First" and "Last" links don't appear by default if you don't need them. It's not very clear from the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html)'s example.
- You won't get "Previous" links until you advance past page 1, the example is actually on page 3 (the "3" is bold).
- Since you're providing your own templates in the configuration instead of using the defaults, your actual results will be slightly different.

If you want to do a quick test to see more links, just reduce your `per_page` to a lower number or include more rows in your `total_rows`. The total number of links shown can also be configured with `num_links`.

Comment: Thanks!! I reduced the links to 5 (for now I only have 18 rows of data) but if I set total_rows a high parameter I get, like you said, the links for First and Last, the problem if if I click on last i go to that page (page number 1000) and it has no data, any other way to simulate that?

Comment: You just need more data. Setting `total_rows` to an arbitrary number is only useful for a quick test to see the links, it's not something you'd actually want to do.

Comment: Thanks, I already set total_rows on 1000, but when I click on the "last" link sends me to the page 1000 ... which has no data... any idea how of to solve it?

Comment: That's probably an issue with the way you're querying the database to generate the actual results (not the pagination count, which is a separate query). In any case, it's a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). We'd have to see your controller code and how you are querying the database.

Comment: I set the controller as update of my question, I tried with both ways, total_rows= 1000 to the database and other only to the pagination, still I keep having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

For those people who developing their CI app with PostgreSql and can't understand why pagination limit+offset works "weird":

**C**ontroller:

```
...
$offset = ($page-1)*$config["per_page"];
$this->reporting_model->some_fetch_method($id, $config["per_page"], $offset);
...
```

**M**odel:

```
...
$this->db->limit($limit_perpage, $offset);
$this->db->where("id",   $id);
$this->db->get('some_table');
...
```