# codeigniters pagination is switching pages but does not switch page number

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

i`m new to code igniter.
the problem is that pagination switches pages correctly,but numeration **1** 2 > does not change.it always stays on first number (does not depend how many pages are there.page number is displayed correctly).

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = base_url()."index.php/news/filter/0/0/";
$config['total_rows'] = $totalRows; //get number or rows
$config['per_page'] = 9;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$data['pages']=$this->pagination->create_links(); // this is used to show on page
```

compare to manual everything is correct.any ideas?

adding $config['uri_segment'] = 5; fixed this.thanks.

Comment: Please try to append `$config['uri_segment'] = 6;` I guest, your pagination segment is `6`

Comment: Where are you getting 6? He only has 4 segments to begin with. Adding the uri_segment will likely fix the issue, it just isn't segment 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take look at this links,

http://phpmaster.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-7-pagination/

[how to configure pagination codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255850/how-to-configure-pagination-codeigniter)